# Using Flatlist in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

How can my flatlist now showing any list, it just show blank inside some 
container:

[image]

here the json Data :

```
{
    "page": 2,
    "per_page": 3,
    "total": 12,
    "total_pages": 4,
    "data": [
        {
            "id": 4,
            "first_name": "Eve",
            "last_name": "Holt",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/marcoramires/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 5,
            "first_name": "Charles",
            "last_name": "Morris",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/stephenmoon/128.jpg"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "first_name": "Tracey",
            "last_name": "Ramos",
            "avatar": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/bigmancho/128.jpg"
        }
    ]
}
```

from regres.in to test the dummy data, and here my code :

```
class UserList extends React.Component {


state = {
        apiAreLoaded: false,


};


constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state.data = [];

}

async componentDidMount() {



    // define the api
    const api = create({
        baseURL: 'https://reqres.in/',
        headers: {
        Accept: 'application/json'
        }
    })

    // start making calls
    //api.get('/api/users?page=2').then((response) => response.data).then(console.log);

    //use async
    const response = await api.get('/api/users?page=2');  
   // console.log(response.data.data);
    this.setState({ apiAreLoaded: true, data: response.data });




   // console.log(this.state.data);  






}

render() {




    if(!this.state.apiAreLoaded)
    {
        return  <AppLoading />;

    }



    return(
        <Container>
            <Content>

                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.data}
                    renderItem={({ item }) => {
                        console.log(data.avatar)
                        return(
                                <ListItem>
                                    <Text>{item.id}</Text>
                                </ListItem>



                        )
                    }}
                />

            </Content>
            </Container>



    );

}


}



export {UserList};
```

For information I am using this version :

> "expo": "^27.0.1",    "native-base": "^2.6.1",
>       "react": "^16.4.1",
>       "react-native": "~0.55.2"

any suggestion ?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a bug, but it also happened to. You have to remove the curly brackets from `renderItem={({ item }) => {`  like this `renderItem=({ item }) => `

Comment: sorry it becomes error

Answer (score 1):

It works now... and here how it works...

1. Make sure you format the api response as the doc say like this :

> data={[{title: 'Title Text', key: 'item1'}, ...]}

note : 
if you use https://reqres.in as dummy data make sure you get the response like this.

`this.setState({ data: response.data.data });`

2. Use Flatlist and keyExtractor here the code sample :

   ```
    <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          keyExtractor={this._keyExtractor}
          renderItem={({item}) => 
          <Text>{item.first_name}</Text>    

    }
     />
   ```
3. See the _keyExtractor, the extractor key used to make virtualized key and here the code :

   `._keyExtractor = (item, index) => index.toString();`